# OKHTTP Sending null in PUT Request

Tags: android, okhttp

I am very new to Android Development and i just learn sending http request through `OKHTTP` i am successfully getting the result for GET and POST Method but i am but able to send PUT request properly.

Here is my Code please take a look.

```
public void btn_reset_click_handler(View view) {
    if (NetworkHelper.hasConnectivity(this)){

        showProgress(true);

        RequestPackage requestPackage = new RequestPackage();
        requestPackage.setEndPoint("reset_password");
        requestPackage.setMethod("PUT");
        requestPackage.setParam("email", username);
        requestPackage.setParam("new_password", password);

        String response = download(requestPackage);

    }else{
        Helper.displayToast(this, "Make Sure you have active network connection!");
    }

}

public static String download(RequestPackage requestPackage) throws IOException {

    String address = requestPackage.getEndpoint();

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder().url(address);

    if (requestPackage.getMethod().equals("POST") || requestPackage.getMethod().equals("PUT")) {

        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM);
        Map<String, String> params = requestPackage.getParams();

        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            builder.addFormDataPart(key, params.get(key));
        }
        RequestBody requestBody = builder.build();
        requestBuilder.method(requestPackage.getMethod(), requestBody);

    }

    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        return response.body().string();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Exception: Response code " + response.code());
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception or failed result?

Comment: there is no exception i found than i tried to var_dum put variable in PHP side i return i can the parameter showing null